# php help - creating default value for specific column on html table

Tags: php

I need some help tweaking this php code to print out a default value for a specific column.

I'm printing out the following column header columns in a table:
`Host Target Date Set Time Length Size Status`

There are instances in the 'tst.txt' input file where I don't have data for the last (3) columns `Length Size Status`

I originally was creating a blank cells for this data, but now I want to put a DEFAULT data for only the column: `Status` 
where if status is null then print `CHECK FOR ERRORS` as an example.

I tried coding that below, but its doing it for every blank cell, but I just want it for column status. Thanks!

```
<?php
$data = array();
$InputFile = file("tst.txt");

foreach ($InputFile as $line){
  preg_match_all("/([0-9])-([^=]+)=([^;]+);/", $line, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
  $LineData = array();
  foreach ($matches as $information)
  {
    $LineData[$information[2]] = $information[3];
  }
  $timestamp = strtotime($LineData["Date"]." ".$LineData["Time"]);
  $data[$timestamp] = $LineData;
}
ksort($data);

$keys = array('Host', 'Target','Date','Set','Time', 'Length','Size','Status');
echo '<table><tr>';
foreach ($keys as $column)
   echo '<th>' . $column . '</th>';
    echo '</tr>';

foreach ($data as $row){
   echo '<tr>';
     foreach ($keys as $column)
        if (isset($row[$column])){
          echo '<td>' . $row[$column];
          } else {
          //echo '<td>' . '' . '</td>';
          echo '<td>' . 'Check for Errors' . '</td>';
        }
}
echo '</table>';
//print_r($data);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($data as $row){
   echo '<tr>';
     foreach ($keys as $column)
        if (isset($row[$column])){
          echo '<td>' . $row[$column] . '</td>';
        } elseif ($column == 'Status') {
          echo '<td> Check for Errors </td>';
        } else {
          echo '<td> </td>';
        }
}
```

is probably about what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks a bunch! that works. I guess, if I want columns `Length` and `Size` with their own default values, just add other elseif conditions right? Thanks again.